# How to properly plot data in Recharts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts

I'm trying to use Recharts to plot some data in an area graph in my React project. I'm not sure what is wrong with the format of the data I'm providing to React, but it's not plotting the actual data points that I'm passing into it. The data I'm passing into the chart is an array that looks like this:

```
[{date: '5:01:59 PM', price: 29209.395363568612},
{date: '6:02:13 PM', price: 29218.857806706103},
{date: '7:01:44 PM', price: 29194.913885389316},
{date: '8:02:37 PM', price: 29256.813374416255},
{date: '9:00:11 PM', price: 29313.84120108591},
{date: '10:00:44 PM', price: 29158.69802123103},
{date: '11:01:37 PM', price: 29227.28615150176},
{date: '12:02:10 AM', price: 29281.41029204116},
{date: '1:01:21 AM', price: 29255.988512722528},
{date: '2:00:56 AM', price: 29290.06697649485},
{date: '3:01:51 AM', price: 29377.041270304915},
{date: '4:01:16 AM', price: 29482.022669025562},
{date: '5:02:41 AM', price: 29403.868537604212},
{date: '6:01:49 AM', price: 29332.91144408883},
{date: '7:01:44 AM', price: 29310.33773441654},
{date: '8:00:01 AM', price: 29310.68064074855},
{date: '9:01:18 AM', price: 29315.265376915155},
{date: '10:00:10 AM', price: 29355.49900328947},
{date: '11:01:40 AM', price: 29408.829445605934},
{date: '12:02:47 PM', price: 29497.347529518447},
{date: '1:02:59 PM', price: 29586.643167160633},
{date: '2:00:12 PM', price: 29456.156222490306},
{date: '3:01:12 PM', price: 29488.44296610853},
{date: '3:28:13 PM', price: 29528.982636104596}]
```

And the Rechart I'm trying to create looks like:

```
    <AreaChart
            width={600}
            height={400}
            data={cryptoData?.oneDay}
            margin={{ top: 10, right: 0, left: 70, bottom: 0 }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="date" />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Area
                type='monotone'
                dataKey='uv'
                stroke='#8884d8'
                fill='#8884d8'
            />
</AreaChart>
```

But the graph just comes out looking like this, and doesn't plot any actual data.
[image]

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong with Recharts here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had the wrong dataKey set in the Area component. I had it set to "pv" when the actual value was the "price".